# monitor beanstalk with cloudwatch

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-cloudwatch

I have multiple beanstalk envs but in cloudwatch I see no way of aggregating by beanstalk environment.

I want to see EC2 and ELB and ASG metrics aggregated by beanstalk environemnt.

Is this possible without having to do custom metrics? If I do have to use custom metrics how would I do this?

EDIT: I can see how this working now. You need enhanced health enabled and then you have to actually choose which metrics you want to track:
[image]

I only saw environment health and didn't realize I needed to tell beanstalk which metrics I want to send cloudwatch

So I assume without enhanced health the only way of getting metrics by beanstalk would be custom metrics?